# Pasar variable ,resultado de una consulta SQL del archivo (consulta.php) a otro con funciones JS

Tags: php, sql, variables

gracias por atender esta consulta. esto necesitan que el resultado de una consulta a la base de datos, pase a otro archivo funciones.php como variables, ARRAY,JSON, y tambien las variables que llegaron por POST del formulario, por ejemplo.

```
  <?php
  header('Content-type:application/json; charset:utf-8');
  include_once "conexion.php";
  $objeto = new Conexion();
  $conexion= $objeto->Conectar();

  $nombre = $_POST["name"];
  $tel = $_POST["telefono"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];


 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM precios WHERE Nombre = $nombre";
  $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
  $resultado -> execute();
  $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  
  $jsondata = json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

Pasar al otro archivo con las funciones .js la respuesta que ahora va al html del inicio con la funcion más abajo, la cúal, también debería estar en ese archivo.

```
  var jsondata = '';
```

para poder usarlas en otra serie de funciones a ejecutarse al hacer click en submit.

ahora tengo un  formulario y el resultado de la consulta lo obtengo en la pàgina de inicio.html

```
   <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="telefono"/>
    <input type="email" name="email"/>
    <input type="submit"  value="Consultar"/>
   </form>
                                    
  <div id="respuesta"></div>
   
    <script>
     var form = document.querySelector('form');
     var boton = document.querySelector('[type=submit]'); 
     form.onsubmit = e => { //function(e){}
     boton.disabled = true;
     var fd = new FormData (form);
 
     e.preventDefault();

     var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest( ); 
     ajax.open( 'POST', 'consulta.php' );
     ajax.upload.onprogress = e =>{
     var porcentaje = e.loaded * 100 / e.total ;
     document.querySelector( '#respuesta' ).innerHTML = porcentaje.toFixed(2)+'%';
       }
    ajax.onload = function( ){
    boton.disabled = false;
    document.querySelector( '#respuesta' ).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
       form.reset();
        }       
        ajax.send(fd); 
     }
    </script>
```

quiero modificar esta funcion, y que se ejecute, al hacer click en el submit del formulario, llamando a otra funcion que la contenga.

```
    <div class="personal_button">
    <a id="finalize" onclick="finalize()" ></a><br>
    </div>
```

desde ya muchas gracias

Gracias. Saludos

Comment: ¿Y para qué querrías hacer algo así? Me explico: si ya tienes persistencia en una base de datos, ¿para qué querrías usar un fichero que, entre otras cosas, se te puede quedar obsoleto?

Comment: En realidad el archivo es php la extrnción,  pero son funciones javascript. Si la extención fuera .js, quizas me

Comment: Edite la pregunta, y esta más claro, gracias